# Space separated values with openpyxl

Tags: openpyxl

Column C has dates in `mm/dd/yy ss-mm-hh` format. I want to remove the `ss-mm-dd` from each cell of that column. How can I do that using `openpyxl`.

Sorry I do not have any script to present at this time since I have no clue where to start.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```py
import openpyxl
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_col=3, max_col=3):
    for cell in row:
        cell.value = cell.value.split()[0]
```